# Flutter textField couse errors on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I am struggling with textfield problem in iOS app. when I click on textField, and type random letters (Latin), I get the following:

```
[Process] 0x112000940 - [PID=73674] WebProcessProxy::didClose: (web process 73674 crash)
[Process] 0x112000940 - [PID=73674] WebProcessProxy::processDidTerminateOrFailedToLaunch: reason=4
[Process] 0x13b897018 - [pageProxyID=6, webPageID=7, PID=73674] WebPageProxy::processDidTerminate: (pid 73674), reason 4
[assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}>
[ProcessSuspension] 0x111004e40 - ProcessAssertion::acquireSync Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'ConnectionTerminationWatchdog' for process with PID=73674, error: Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}
[Loading] 0x13b897018 - [pageProxyID=6, webPageID=7, PID=73674] WebPageProxy::dispatchProcessDidTerminate: reason=Crash
[ServicesDaemonManager] interruptionHandler is called. -[FontServicesDaemonManager connection]_block_invoke
[XPC] Handle connection with error: Connection interrupted
Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service
[Process] 0x112001930 - [PID=74275] WebProcessProxy::didBecomeUnresponsive:
[Process] 0x13a780018 - [pageProxyID=360, webPageID=361, PID=74275] WebPageProxy::processDidBecomeUnresponsive:
[assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}>
[ProcessSuspension] 0x111006580 - ProcessAssertion::acquireSync Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'WebProcess Suspended Assertion' for process with PID=73685, error: Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}
```

In addition, the entire application starts to lag and sometimes crashes.

The important thing is that the heap memory stays around ~20MB so it shouldn't cause such problems

I created a new project to reproduce the problem, and the problem did not occur. Can anyone point me to what could be causing this behaviour on iOS? I don't even use webView.

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SearchScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SearchScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: TextFormField(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am shocked that such a simple thing causes so many problems